# post__in not taking my list of IDs

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I have a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) on a page named `banner_id_list`.

I have a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) called `top_banner`. I add a few banners, note the IDs and then go back to the page and add a comma delimited list of IDs in the `banner_id_list` custom field.

In my template, the plan is to check the current posts meta using [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). That should produce a list of IDs that I can then take and use in get_posts() with `post__in = array()` (see [post__in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)).

Now on to the code, I'm missing something here but I'm a bit of a newb at this.

```
// get the banner_id_list based on the meta custom field for this page
$banner_id_list = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner_id_list', true);
```

If I dump that I see the expected data, a list of IDs I entered into the custom field.

Now for my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'top_banner',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,        
    'order' => ASC,
    'orderby' => menu_order,
    'post__in' => array($banner_id_list)
 ); 

 $banners = get_posts($args);
```

But there's something funky about using `$banner_id_list` here. It's only getting a single record. But if I manually enter values in place of that variable, it works properly.

I think it's something simple/fundamental I'm missing, hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$banner_id_list` holds comma-delimited list then to convert it to array instead of

```
array($banner_id_list)
```

you need to do

```
explode(',', $banner_id_list)
```

Comment: or `wp_parse_id_list`  (does some extra checks)