# post__in works but also prints the word Array

Tags: array

First line of the code below carries post ids captured via a form. Then rest of the code helps pull the post-thumbnail of the respective post ids

```
$sel_ids = $_SESSION['selected_ids'];
if ( ! is_array( $sel_ids ) ) { //the check to prove that $sel_ids is a valid array
return;
}

require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$args = array( 'post__in' => $sel_ids, 'post_type' => 'post' );
$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'coverimage');
}
```

[image]

> Thumbnails display fine but before the thumbnails, the code also
>   outputs a word `Array` which is definitely unwanted.

---

I have tried commenting out the lines one by one to isolate what line exactly is the culprit. So I found that this line `$args = array( 'post__in' => $sel_ids, 'post_type' => 'post' );` generates the unwanted string `Array`. My guess is the var  `$sel_ids` needs some work.

**FYI** a `var_dump($sel_ids)` prints `array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "67" [1]=> string(2) "16" }`. I also tried the code `explode(',', $sel_ids);` from the [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20981/post-in-not-taking-my-list-of-ids#answer-20983) but it prints a warning `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string`. Which I think makes sense because I know that $sel_ids is an array, but then why is it printing the word `Array`, odd.

---

**FYI** Since the code is a part of an html email. Here is a relevant part of the source of the email in gmail. Just in case it helps to infer the issue better.

```
Array<img src="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/360.jpg">
```

---

**UPDATE** : Test code `<pre><?php print_r($args);?></pre>` outputs the results below. I suspect the word `Array` is being printed out from `[post__in] => Array`. How do I remove or replace this.

```
Array
(
    [post__in] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 16
        )

    [post_type] => post
)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure `Array` is not printing from somewhere else? Not relevant but you should use `the_post_thumbnail()` when echo the html. Also there should be `if(!empty($posts))` check before try to loop through `$posts`.

Comment: @Sisir `if(!empty($posts))` does not make any difference. In fact any line after `$args = array( 'post__in'.......` do not print anything, I have seen so by commenting all other lines. `the_post_thumbnail()` is irrelevant as I need to grab the image url by post ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` is how PHP represents an array when it is converted to a string:

```
echo array( /* anything in here */ ); // output: Array
```

Fortunately for you, PHP doesn't really like converting arrays to strings, so it will give an error like this:

> PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in /somefile.php on line 345

Usually these PHP notices are silenced by default. To see them, you should enable WordPress debugging mode with [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG). Frankly, you should have `WP_DEBUG` enabled any time you are developing something with WordPress :-).

Once you've enabled debugging mode, run your code and [check the `debug.log`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG#WP_DEBUG_LOG). You should see an array to string conversion notice from PHP, which will tell you where this came from.

Like @Sisir, I don't see any problems with your code. I suspect that the array is being output by a function hooked to one of the actions or filters called by `get_the_post_thumbnail()`: `'post_thumbnail_size'`, `'begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html'`, `'end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html'`, and `'post_thumbnail_html'`.